# Nuance Transcription Engine not running on Docker

Tags: docker

I am currently attempting to run the NTE in a docker container with no success.

The issue I am facing is that the Nuance Transcription Engine refuses to start with the following error -

> 2017-12-06T12:15:53.402Z - error: Error initializing recipe executor message=error initializing transcriber: TypeError: MREC failure during initialization of Fast
>   Pass module
>
> 2017-12-06T12:15:53.407Z - fatal: Error: [/mrec/release/mrec/1.34.100/17834/src/fileutil/dsmsetdata.cpp 975 2] SDVoc_NewFromFile: MREC-{d4fdd844-90d8-5bb4-9899-01
>   3410017834}-{186fb965-6316-5a3d-8e46-68769c99fb0e}-ilgls-SDAPI-{ec4e36b2-c053-470c-91fd-bece096fefe6}-record MREC-{d4fdd844-90d8-5bb4-9899-013410017834}-{186fb965
>   -6316-5a3d-8e46-68769c99fb0e}-ilgls-SDAPI-{ec4e36b2-c053-470c-91fd-bece096fefe6}-record (See mrec/doc/client.txt for general documentation on errors.) source=latt
>   icegeneratoraddon.node

I have verified that the docker containers for the licensing server and transcription engine have access to each other, and I have done some investigating with **STRACE** to see the system calls that are being made.

> Strace Output :
>
> rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [INT CHLD], NULL, 8) = 0
>   clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f0b4b8a49d0) = 227
>   rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
>   rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
>   rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
>   rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
>   rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x43d6c0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f0b4af0b510}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f0b4af0b510}, 8) = 0
>   wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 227
>   rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
>   --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=227, si_status=0, si_utime=184, si_stime=17} ---
>   wait4(-1, 0x7ffd6d7c9adc, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
>   rt_sigreturn()                          = 0
>   rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f0b4af0b510}, {0x43d6c0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f0b4af0b510}, 8) = 0
>   rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
>   read(255, "", 508)                      = 0
>   exit_group(0)                           = ?
>
> +++ exited with 0 +++

What I have noticed is that the child process spawned by the clone system call is killed in docker, whereas the exact same process works fine on the host itself.

Here is some information about the system:

docker version
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d/1.7.1
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d/1.7.1
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64

lsb-release:
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-ia32:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:pri
nting-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch

Docker container lsb-release:
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-ia32:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:pri
nting-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch

Host OS: CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
Docker container OS: CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

I apologize in advance if the question is off-topic.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Nuance has been clear they don't offer support for Docker. They did, however, provide a work around which I've yet to verify works. It may be of help to you however:

> The article is for NTE3.1, you can use it as reference. There is no guarantee that this will work with NTE4.
>
> Requirements
>
> Although NTE officially supports RHEL 6, it is strongly advised to use RHEL 7 as Docker officially requires kernel 3.10 or later. You can currently install Docker 1.7 via EPEL 6 but it is an old release at this point and had to be exceptionally (and reluctantly) modified to support RHEL 6. From what we can understand, this exception will not be repeated.
>
> Limitations
>
> NTE's current design makes each instance stateful with its own job queue. The benefits of Docker are therefore limited as you cannot simply add an instance to a pool of engines behind a load balancer. The use of shared memory between instances can also only be taken advantage of when containers are deployed on the same host. In fact, each container must rely on the host's shared memory (/dev/shm). Although Docker allows you to create an isolated chunk of shared memory for your containers to share, it is always mounted as noexec and therefore incompatible with MREC. When the host's /dev/shm is used, its original mounting parameters are left as-is.
>
> Use of Docker for the license manager is also not currently recommended. It's third-party software and binds to a MAC address. The process of inserting a license file also requires manual intervention via a web portal.
>
> Suggested Architecture
>
> If Docker is limited by NTE's design, what can we do to benefit from containers? Deploying multiple engines on the same server is currently the best use case. Since each process will live in its own namespace, this brings the following advantages: 
>   ?Configuration files can be shared across containers, including HTTP/HTTPS ports. Different port-forwarding rules will have to be configured per instance but as far as each NTE process will be concerned it will be listening on port 8080 and writing logs into $NTE_DATA_DIR. 
>   ?Using a tool like Docker Compose, we can easily configure, bring up or down multiple instances of NTE all at once.
>
> Here are sample files for a Docker Compose environment:
>
> Dockerfile
>
> FROM centos:7
>
> COPY ./nte-3.1.1-201609292006.el6.x86_64.rpm /tmp/
>
> RUN yum -y update
>
> RUN yum -y install /tmp/nte-3.1.1-201609292006.el6.x86_64.rpm
>
> RUN rm /tmp/nte-3.1.1-201609292006.el6.x86_64.rpm
>
> common.yml
>
> version: '2'
>
> services:
>
> nte:
>
> build: .
>
> image: nte:3.1.1
>
> working_dir: $NTE_ROOT_DIR
>
> entrypoint: bash -c ./startEngine.sh
>
> ipc: host
>
> ulimits:
>
> core:
>
> soft: -1
>
> hard: -1
>
> volumes:
>
> - /tmp/cores:/tmp/cores
> - $NTE_DATA_DIR/config:$NTE_DATA_DIR/config
> - $NTE_DATA_DIR/language_packs:$NTE_DATA_DIR/language_packs
> - $NTE_ROOT_DIR/licenses:$NTE_ROOT_DIR/licenses
>
> docker-compose.yml
>
> version: '2'
>
> services:
>
> nte1:
>
> extends:
>
> file: common.yml
>
> service: nte 
>   container_name: "nte-instance-1"
>
> ports: 
>   - "8080:8080" 
>   nte2:
>
> extends:
>
> file: common.yml
>
> service: nte
>
> container_name: "nte-instance-2"
>
> ports:
>
> - "8081:8080"
>
> The Dockerfile is simple. When we build the NTE Docker image, we simply copy an NTE RPM, install it and then remove it.
>
> common.yml contains the shared specification between all instances. This is where we can configure the common parameters, such as the entry point (command to launch when a container is started), the shared folders between the host and container, the IPC namespace and the ulimits.
>
> docker-compose.yml is what Docker Compose actually reads as input. This is where the instances (or services, in Docker Compose parlance) are concretely defined. In this scenario, we have two NTE engines: nte1 and nte2. They both inherit the specification in common.yml, with the addition of container-specific information, such as what port should be open on the host to communicate with the engines. nte1 will be reachable via port 8080 on the host and nte2 via port 8081.
>
> Note that port forwarding is only necessary for situations where the engines need to be accessed from processes outside of your Docker environment. For example, if the only client issuing calls to NTE was your web server, you could run that server inside of a container and it would be able to access each of the engines via Docker's private network.
>
> With all of this set up, calling 'docker-compose up' will launch nte1 and nte2 simultaneously.

If you manage to get this working I'd love to hear about how.

Answer (score 0):

Mount **tmfs - /dev/shm** and run with **--privileged**

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM centos:7

ENV NTE_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/Nuance/Transcription_Engine
ENV NTE_DATA_DIR=/var/local/Nuance/Transcription_Engine

ADD license /license
COPY install/nte-3.1.0-201609260952.el6.x86_64.rpm /install/nte.rpm
COPY install/nte-por-bra-3.1.6-3.0.0-201605182043.el6.noarch.rpm /install/nte-por-bra.rpm
COPY entrypoint.sh /app/entrypoint.sh

RUN yum install -y /install/nte.rpm /install/nte-por-bra.rpm net-tools bc && rm -rf /install

COPY install/development.yaml $NTE_DATA_DIR/config/development.yaml

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /dev/shm
mount  -t tmpfs -o defaults tmpfs /dev/shm

cd $NTE_ROOT_DIR && sh startEngine.sh
```

**Build and run**

```
docker build -t nte:v3 .
docker run -it --rm --net=host --privileged nte:v3
```